# Detener submit de formulario luego disparar desde modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un formulario que al hacer click para enviar muestro un modal para confirmar, podria hacer lo mismo con un alert pero por razones de estetica muestro un modal que tiene un boton, ese boton confirma el envio del form

Quisiera que el boton del modal dispare el formulario, como podria hacer esto con jquery

tengo lo siguiente:

#### Datos de Comprador

```
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, vel odio non dicta provident sint ex autem mollitia dolorem illum repellat ipsum aliquid illo similique sapiente fugiat minus ratione.</p>



    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmar compra</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
                                        <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
                                        <p>
                                            <a href="" class="button button-3d notopmargin fleft" id="comprar" >Proceder a la compra</a>
                                        </p>
                                        <p>&nbsp;</p>



                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   

 <form method="POST" action="proceso.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
 id="procesar"><input name="_token" type="hidden" 
 value="Lj6ETkI7zq0lLWcu4nX2pGHh3kQeX6RpuazUIzHY">

    <div class="col_half">


        <label for="billing-form-name">Nombre</label>
        <input class="sm-form-control" name="addressline" type="text">

    </div>

    <div class="col_half col_last">
        <label for="billing-form-lname">Apellido</label>
        <input class="sm-form-control" name="billing-form-lname" type="text" 
        id="billing-form-lname">

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ruc">RUC / CI</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="ruc" type="text" id="ruc">
    </div>


    <input class="button success" id="proc_cart" data-toggle="modal" data-
    target=".bs-example-modal-lg" type="submit" value="Procesar pedido">
    </form>
```

Luego mi script seria:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     var custom2=jQuery;
     custom2.noConflict();

     custom2(document).ready(function() {

        custom2( "#proc_cart" ).click( function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

        });

        custom2( "#comprar" ).click( function(event){

            $("#procesar").trigger('submit');

            //alert('hola');
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba agregar esta linea `event.preventDefault();` quedando asi

```
custom2( "#comprar" ).click( function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#procesar").trigger('submit');

        //alert('hola');
    });
```

si no te ayuda esto pon que error te esta dando para aclararnos un poco mas
espero te ayude probe tu codigo y esto era lo que faltaba.

Comment: Me funciono con event.preventDefault(); y en custom2("#procesar").trigger('submit');  gracias!